# Framework/Library like Sitemesh

Tags: html, design-patterns, web-applications, frameworks, sitemesh

I am looking at a UI framework similar to Sitemesh

http://www.sitemesh.org/

Just to add, I am planning to have a Java based web app, which would be based on fluid design and would have "slightly" different layouts for desktop/mobile/tablet. (e.g. some areas just rearranging on different screen sizes or even hidden on smaller screens, etc)

Please suggest whatever ideas you may have.